# Basic .htaccess mod_rewrite. (More defined)

Tags: php, regex, apache, .htaccess

Continuing from [**previous question**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/623161/help-with-basic-htaccess-modrewrite)

I was told to use

```
RewriteRule ^error/(.*) index.php?error=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^file/(.*) index.php?file=$1 [L]
```

and

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.mysite\.com$ [NC]
```

before each, but it dosn't really help me specifically.

I am using a wildcard sub-domain how can I make this condition:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.mysite\.com$ [NC]
```

dynamic, like if it is any subdomain (except www.) so what do I need to change.

Comment: I edited the last part, its changing the cond to use a wildcard subdomain instead of www and how to ignore if it is www

Comment: Why don’t you just alter your previous question?

Comment: Do you know the answer..

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand your question, but it may help to recall that the second arg to RewriteCond is a regexp so you could write something like:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^[a-z]+\.mysite\.com$ [NC]
```

As for excluding www you can chain rules (they are anded together) or get fancy with your regular expression.  I'd suggest the former as it's generally easier to follow.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you understood [Gumbo's advice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/623161/help-with-basic-htaccess-modrewrite/624024#624024). I've included it here:

```
# stop rewriting for the host names example.com and www.example.com
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?example\.com$
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

RewriteRule ^error/(.*) index.php?error=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^file/(.*) index.php?file=$1 [L]
```

This specifically performs no-rewrite for www.example.com and example.com. If we're on *any other* subdomain of example.com, the error/ and file/ rewrites apply.

If you wanted to invert the test, you could do something like this:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^(www\.)?example\.com$
RewriteRule ^error/(.*) index.php?error=$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^(www\.)?example\.com$
RewriteRule ^file/(.*) index.php?file=$1 [L]
```

Answer (score 0):

I used php and created a system for my framework, its more efficient and secure in many ways I think, but thanks alot for the advice!

:]<3

Answer (score 0):

This got me out of similar situations building complex Regex, it might help you out as well.

http://www.addedbytes.com/apache/mod_rewrite-cheat-sheet/