# Can I do use a direct URL like twitter or myspace in PHP

Tags: php, html, url

Can I do that thing that twitter and many other sites do where a url shows a users page.

www.mysite.com/the_user_name

In php... or how does one do it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Look into how to use [the mod_rewrite module in .htaccess](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/623161/help-with-basic-htaccess-modrewrite).

Here's some ALA goodness:

1. [How to Succeed With URLs](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/succeed/)
2. [URLS! URLS! URLS!](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/urls/)

Comment: Thanks. Just had no idea what to even look for. Now I got it!

Answer (score 3):

The easiest method would be to use [`mod_rewrite`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/1.3/mod/mod_rewrite.html) in Apache (as opposed to doing it in PHP).  Here's a good [beginner's guide](http://www.workingwith.me.uk/articles/scripting/mod_rewrite).

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way that I know of is to create a .htaccess file for the website with the RewriteEngine turned on.

For example

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^(.+) /index.php?user=$1
```

Do a google search for .htaccess and RewriteEngine to get a better grasp of the process or creating an .htaccess file.